# Unexpected error while request parsing using a serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-serializer

While parsing my request data from front-end and converting into JSON format using a serializer. I am getting some unexpected errors.

while request parsing pattern using serializers given as mentioned below, it shows me the following error:(I found the below error using: contact_serializer.errors)

```
{'address': {u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it will work like this. You have to remember here is that if you input the values like this, it will ultimately be stored in DB, and it is hard coded values. Even if you insist to do it like this, then use a list of dictionary like this:

```
request.data['phone_number'] = [{'number': '9999999999'}]
request.data['cont_email'] = [{'email':'tim@gmail.com'}]
```

And update the serializer like this:

```
class CrmContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberSerializer(source = 'contact_number', many=True)
    cont_email = ContactEmailSerializer(source = 'contact_email', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantContactAssociation
        fields = ('id','phone_number','cont_email','contact')

    def create(self, validated_data):
         phone_number = validated_data.pop('contact_number')
         cont_email = validated_data.pop('contact_email')

         restaurant = super(CrmContactSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
         phone_instance = PhoneNumber(**phone_number)
         phone_instance.restaurant = restaurant
         phone_instance.save()

         email_instance = ContactEmail(**phone_number)
         email_instance.restaurant = restaurant
         email_instance.save()
         return restaurant
```

Reason for `many=True` is that one restaurant can have multiple numbers or emails(as it has one to many relationship with respective models).

Now, if you think of proper way of implementing, you can make `phone_number` and `cont_email` read only fields, so that it will be used when only reading, not writing:

```
class CrmContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberSerializer(source = 'contact_number', read_only=True)
    cont_email = ContactEmailSerializer(source = 'contact_email', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantContactAssociation
        fields = ('id','phone_number','cont_email','contact')
```

In that way, validation error can be handled for phone number and cont email.

Comment: If you don't want to make them read only, you can always send those values from frontend and store it in DB. in that case you need to remove `read_only=True`

Comment: `CrmContactSerializer(RestaurantContactAssociation.objects.all(), many=True).data` should get you the data you need.

Comment: @Timshrok please see the updated answer. ` If I need to have this in format from front-end`, if you mean by how to send this data, then I think you need share how you are sending data from frontend to backend

Comment: Hi @ruddra, please check-update 2. key-error pops up.

Comment: can you please print(`validated_data`) and see what keys you are getting?

Comment: Are you using python 2.7? I have updated the answer

Comment: The create line in serializer is the cause of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210210/discussion-between-timshrok-and-ruddra).

Comment: can you share your full view?

Comment: can you please come on the chat?

Comment: Hi @ruddra, can you please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853584/type-mismatch-in-django-serializer-for-request-parsing/60854054#60854054